# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when connecting to web service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, ionic-framework

Hi I know there is a lot of questions about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `CORS` but haven't exactly found something for my issue. I don't have any experience with `CORS` so any help will be appreciated. I have a ionic app which I want to use to connect to a WCF web service on a website domain. I also have connected to the service locally on my localhost and it worked, but not when connecting to the domain with my localhost.

these are the errors I am getting.

`GET http://www.website.com/webservice/Service.svc`

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://http://www.website.com/webservice/Service.svc. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

coding

```
HTML:
  <p>{{Success + " " + Error}}</p>

Javascript:
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://www.website.com/webservice/Service.svc")
  .success(function(data){
   $scope.Success = "SUCCESS!";
  })
  .error(function(data){
    $scope.Error = "ERROR!";
  });    

})
```

I am testing on my browser using `ionic serve` and I have tried connecting with `Ionic view` app

this I added in my WCF service

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: Must visit http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api for your problem.

Comment: Check with fiddler or firebug if the header is really present. If not, your configuration is wrong. Maybe you are using a self-hosted wcf service? Then you must configure cors in your code.

Comment: Set the same header when you send response from server

Comment: Do you mean setting the same header in my app? @RohitKumar

Comment: Yes!!! Otherwise how would the server know that it is open to serve request from any domain???

Comment: Sorry I have tried adding jquery - ajax header but doesnt seem to work could you reference me to an article that could clearify this for me? @RohitKumar

Comment: where is your server??? the one you are hitting to get the data

Comment: If I had a server on node and I had to allow others to access my resource, I would serve the response after setting the response like :
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');